# React Native WebView Refresh on iframe form submit - iOS

Tags: ios, forms, react-native, iframe, webview

I have a WebView which loads a web form containing within an iframe  as shown below.

[image]

It should go to the next step (again an iframe similar to the screenshot where the url remains the same) once the "next" button is pressed with valid credentials. However, in iOS it keep refreshing the page, but it works successfully in Android and also if I launch the page independently in Safari browser in iOS, it works just fine.

Additionally I integrated the Safari browser using "SafariServices" to the app but ended up refreshing the page again as before.

Can someone help me figuring out how to get it to work?

I am using the WebView as below

```
      <WebView
        style={styles.WebViewStyle}
        source={{uri: newStudentUrl}}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        scalesPageToFit={true}
        renderLoading={this.ActivityIndicatorLoadingView}
        startInLoadingState={true}
      />
```

Thanks. Your help is greatly appreciated